# Recording screen interaction for UI playback

Tags: screenshot, xdotool

Before I resort to scripting my own, is there a tool that records screen interactions for playback?

I want to record where the mouse got clicked and on which menu, in order to automate a series of steps.

I am planning to use `xdotool` to play back actions - but I am open to better alternatives, so my plan is to have a script record mouse position and take a screenshot at regular intervals, and then edit the results.

kind of like this (untested yet, and screenshot file name clearly needs to change):

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    gnome-screenshot -pf foo.png
    xdotool getmouselocation
    sleep 2
done
```

Any better solutions out there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any macro recorder programs availiable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752325/any-macro-recorder-programs-availiable)

Answer (score 1):

I was using x-macro for a while. The xmacroplay function still seems to work for the macros I have already recorded, but I'm having issues being able to generate a new macro using the xmacrorec2 function.  When I run it, it asks for a button to end the application, and recommends ESC.  But when I press ESC, or any other button for that matter, it doesn't allow me to perform functions outside of the terminal until I cancel the recording.  Perhaps you can get it to work.  When I used it before, it was very convenient, but now...